# How to pass data from html web resource to dynamics 365 ce

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I want to pass data from my dynamic html table on button click event to model driven app account form in dynamic 365 crm. But I'm not be able to pass the data. Please refer the below java script function that I used to pass data.

```js
function addAddress(event) {
    var row = $(event);
    var parent = row.parent();
    parent = parent.parent();

    window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_line1").setValue(parent.closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text());
    window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_line2").setValue(parent.closest("tr").find('td:eq(1)').text());
    window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_line3").setValue(parent.closest("tr").find('td:eq(2)').text());
    window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_city").setValue(parent.closest("tr").find('td:eq(3)').text());
    window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_stateorprovince").setValue(parent.closest("tr").find('td:eq(4)').text());
    window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_country").setValue(parent.closest("tr").find('td:eq(6)').text());
}
```

Comment: Vanilla js or jquery?

Comment: @J.S.Orris I used jquery function

Comment: https://softchief.com/2022/03/14/crud-operation-from-html-web-resource-using-javascript-in-dynamics-365-ce-crm/

Comment: FYI you are using deprecated javascript. We now use formContext instead of Xrm.Page.  var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext(). You need to pass executionContext as parameter to your js from web resource config.

Answer (score 1):

One simple option is to refactor your code to use the [postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) function. Once that button is clicked on your HTML WebResource, you can post a message that can be handled by the form which can take action based on that.

As an example, when X event is triggered on your HTML WebResource, the following code sends a message (you can format your object whatever you like) to the parent window (account form):

```
// Please change the targetOrigin parameter
window.parent.postMessage({ "line1": "value1",  "line2": "value2"}, "*");
```

On your account form JS WebResource, the following code registers an event handler that will listen for your message and take action using the `_formContext` object which can be saved on the onLoad event (as a replacement of Xrm.Page which has been deprecated):

```
 window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
 // Important. Only accept messages from trusted origins
    if (event.origin === "XXX") {
       var messageData = event.data;
       _formContext.getAttribute("address1_line1").setValue(messageData.line1);
       _formContext.getAttribute("address1_line2").setValue(messageData.line2);
    }
});
```

It's important that you use the `postMessage` and `addEventListener` methods on the correct window object so if the above code doesn't work as is (I've just taken the Mozilla documentation code and changed it to fit your scenario) please review this, as you might need to change `window.addEventListener` to `window.parent.addEventListener`.

Comment: Federicos approach seems correct to me. The web resource is rendered in an iframe. So you got to use the postmessage mechanics to bubble your data up to the parent window.
Maybe consider another approach by calling an action/plugin with your payload from the web resource and update form/entity data by using c# if the data gets more complex.